# Loading XML Files during Maven Test run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have a very basic question on usage of resource files (like XML etc.) for Junit tests in a Maven build environment.
There were few related questions to this topic here but it answered my question only partly. I am hoping someone can give a comprehensive answer for this issue

I need clarification on

1. If I keep my resource files under src/test/resources/, to load this file in my unit test during maven build, what is file system path I should provide?
2. The same unit tests are also run at an individual level by developers in their own environments i.e. Without using maven test goal and directly using a run config in Eclipse.

What is the best way to support both these run scenario and keeping the files in a single location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) so that you are not depend upon the file paths.

Read this turorial: [Accessing Resources](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html)

Comment: @Fazal, does this answer work for you?  I've run into cases where tests really need to access the files via the O/S.

Comment: In that instance I would load a configuration file that contains the file paths in the above manner.

Comment: @Chris, I'm not sure where you meant to load the config file from.  I presumed the requirement/desire was (or might be) to be able to have project-relative paths work during testing in some way, as they would with Ant, IDE's, etc.  The cases I'm thinking about are things like xsd references in xml files.  There are ways to implement entity resolvers, xml catalog, etc., but it's a bit much for just testing.

Comment: Use Class.getResourseAsStream() to load a config file containing the necessary path information.  This way the config file is loaded in a platform independent way and the paths therein can be used to access the local OS's filesystem.